# Saisissez vs. Cle

Tags: traduction, anglais

I'm under the impression that the words "saisissez" and "clé" mean the same thing: "key". Is there a meaningful difference between the two words? Do they have any alternate meanings?

Comment: Do you have examples where you saw "saisissez" ? "Saisir" means "to type (on a keyboard)"...

Comment: "cle" is not a word in French, you must think about "clef" or "clé", two correct ways to write "key" in French.

Comment: @AnneAunyme I meant the "clé". My keyboard does not support an accent aigu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do not mean at all the same thing.

*Saisissez* is a conjugated form of *saisir* which has a lot of meanings like grasp, grab, enter, while *clé* is a noun, not a verb, meaning key but not the kind of keys used on a keyboard which are named *touches*.

Comment: I figured out what the misunderstanding was -- "saisissez" in the context I saw it was *to key*, i.e. to type in, but in the translation it was translated directly as *key*.